# React with Asp.net Core Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

This is my index.js file of react.js with Asp.net Core i am getting this error when i am running it from Visual Studio Enterprise Edition

````
    <Router history={history}>
        <div>
            <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Redirect to="/jsplumb" />} />
            <Route path="/jsplumb" component={JsPlumbDemo} />
            <Route path="/jointjs" component={JointJSDemo} />
        </div>
    </Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
registerServiceWorker();```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reason i am getting this error is because in my index.html in public folder the Id needs to be app which was Root before